# QGIS-attribute table messed up after using field calculator

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

When I duplicate my layer and add fields to run simple opérations with the field calculator, the attribute table of all my layers is messed up, it's been a week this is happening, do you know why and how to remedy that?
[image]

Comment: You are aware that a duplicate of a layer still uses the same shapefile?

Comment: I don't understand how you comment can help to solve my problem here, could you clarify?

Comment: It looks like you've corrupted the dBase component of the shapefile. At this point, every layer using that shapefile is corrupted/useless. dBase has a maximum width of 4000 bytes/record, which may be the root cause of this problem. You'll need to use a backup of your dataset to get some semblance of functionality, at which point I suggest you convert a less limited data format.

Comment: When you said all your layer are messed do you mean the one you edit and the duplicate or other layer are also messed ? Is the problem permanent (ie. the attribute table is corrupt) or if you add the shapefile in a new document is it good ?

Comment: Thank you both, Vince, so i should always have back up of my data and then if it is messed up start the operation again or should I make sure I don't do to many operations?

Comment: JR, When I edit one layer then all the duplicates get automatically messed up too...

Comment: Sorry, you should understand one very, very crucial fact: if you duplicate a layer, you do **NOT** duplicate the data source. You have two layers that both access the same data source. So changing data in one layer affectes the same data on the other layer, too. To avoid that, you should create a copy of the data source, not duplicate the layer.

Comment: Thank you so much! even if when I duplicate the layer I export it and save it on my computer with an other name?